# Passing arguments through timer.PerformWithDelay - Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning Lua language. I'm a little bit confused.
I want to pass argument to function through timer.PerformWithDelay method. Here is code which I wrote:

```
local function animate ( event )
    gear.rotation = gear.rotation + rotateAmount;
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);
------------------------------------------------
function reverseRotate()
    if tonumber(rtAm) > 0 then  -- here appear error: "Attempt to compare number with nil"
        rotateAmount = rotateAmount - 1;
    elseif tonumber(rtAm) < 0 then
        rotateAmount = rotateAmount + 1;
    end
end
------------------------------------------------
local buttonHandler = function ( event )
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        local iteration = math.abs(rotateAmount);
            if rotateAmount > 0 then
                local rtAm = rotateAmount;
                timer.performWithDelay(100, function() reverseRotate ("rtAm") end, 2*iteration);
            elseif rotateAmount < 0 then
                local rtAm = rotateAmount;
                timer.performWithDelay(100, function() reverseRotate ("rtAm") end, 2*iteration);
            end
    end
end
```

So my question is: why variable rtAm isn't passing to reverseRotation function?

Comment: `function reverseRotate(rtAm) if rtAm > 0 ...` and `function()reverseRotate(rtAm)end`

Comment: Of course I forgot to add rtAm in round brackets...Also rewrote quotation marks from docs :D Silly meeeee. Thanks Egor!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff please post your comment in the answers section.
Neru, please accept his answer once it's there.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, stop answering in comments! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string literal in your call instead of the variable. Change

```
timer.performWithDelay(100, function() reverseRotate ("rtAm") end, 2*iteration);
```

to

```
timer.performWithDelay(100, function() reverseRotate(rtAm) end, 2*iteration);
```